# Credential Provider DLL doesn't load properly when built using debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, credential-providers

I have built the DLL in release mode for x64 successfully. After registering it with the Register.reg file, the Crdential Provider loads properly when I lock my computer.

However, when I build in Debug mode for x64, my Credential Provider will not load when I lock my computer. Is there something wrong with my build configuration? What do I need to check?

Comment: Is the debug version of the runtime (msvc?????d.dll, blahblahblah) available in the environment path?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes, I have msvcp120d.dll and msvcr120d.dll in System32.

Comment: @Matt have you been able to figure out what caused this? I am running into the same issue now as well

Comment: @jvpernis I think at the time I just printed log statements instead to work around it. It was a long time ago... don't remember if I ever got it working again, but if I did, I wouldn't be able to give you repeatable steps. Sorry. Try updating everything, rebooting, and maybe also try it in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably not facing this, but it might be relevant for anyone else stumbling onto this question.

In my situation, I was running the Credential Provider on a different machine than I was building the code on. As it turns out, I did not have the debug version of the C++ Runtime files installed on the target machine.

The debug runtime files are not shipped with the normal C++ redistributable package which you can download from Microsoft's website. They are only available from your Visual Studio installation (see [this reference for Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/2017-redistribution-vs#visual-c-runtime-files)).

Copy the contents of the folllowing folder:

- `[VisualStudioFolder]\VC\Redist\MSVC\[version]\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC[version].DebugCRT\`

To:

- `C:\Windows\System32`

Also make sure to change the owner of the manually copied files to the `SYSTEM` user.

Note that these files are not allowed to be distributed along with your application, they are only available for development puposes.